# Allow network interface configuration without root priviledges

Tags: networking, ubuntu, permissions, network-interface

I have second network interface and I want to allow non-root users to configure it (Ubuntu).
Is it possible to do this with udev or setcap?  What should I rather use and how?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Instead of naming the problem as solved, use the Answer box below to say what you did to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow network interface, for example `eth1` to user `cisco`, edit `/etc/sudoers` with a "safe editor" like vim:

```
cisco All = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig eth1 *
```

NOTE: Taken from the OP's edit to his post